# Import Global list to Azure DevOps Hosted XML Process template

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, devops

I performed a TFS to Azure DevOps(VSTS) migration for a customer.
The target process template is an Hosted XML Process template.
According to Microsoft's documentation, it is possible to import Global lists to the Organization(collection), but when trying to import via Witadmin (Tried with the tool from VS15 and VS17), the action failed with the following error :

> *Server was unable to process request. ---> VS1640129: The collection you are targeting uses inheritance process model. This operation is
>   not allowed on an inheritance process model based collection. Please
>   refer to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=849010 or contact
>   your system administrator for help.*

**I am not using Inheritance process model!**

[All processes window in Azure DevOps web access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABrkx.png)

the command :

> witadmin importgloballist
>   /collection:https://collectionName.visualstudio.com
>   /f:"C:\GloballistFolder\GlobalList.xml"

Ideas?

Comment: I'm facing this same issue. Were you able to get it resolved?

Answer (score 1):

I found Microsoft's response in the comments [on this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/338672/view.html).

> Global lists are now part of a specific work item. To edit the list
>   you should 1) export the process 2) look into the xml for the work
>   items. Global lists are usually added to the bug or task wit 3) make
>   the global list changes in the xml 4) zip up the process and import
>   back into Azure DevOps.

So it seems that we should no longer be using the `witadmin.exe` tool for exporting and importing global lists, and instead export the entire process via the web portal (from the Organization settings -> Process page), modify the work item type definitions you're interested in, and re-import the entire process via the web portal.

It looks like the Azure DevOps API supports [exporting and importing the process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processadmin/processes/export%20process%20template?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) template as well, if you wanted to partially automate the process.